# how we get aws-s3 bucket data if user want to give the bucket name using javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I want to get the aws-s3 bucket name from the user using javascript and I want to show the bucket data in the browser.

I have made a function that will take a bucket name from html page and then it would show the desired output.

```
function loadBucket(){
  const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region: '**-*****-*',
    accessKeyId: '************,
    secretAccessKey: '********************'
  });

  var bucket = document.getElementById('bucketName').value;
  var params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    MaxKeys: 5
  }
  s3.listObjects(params, function(err,data) {
    if (err) console.log("error is  : " + err)
    else console.log(data.Contents); 
  });
}
```

I expected the output to be in JSON form like:

```
{
  name: "xyz",
  age: 20
}
```

Instead, I'm getting the following error:

```
aws-sdk-2.476.0.min.js:62 OPTIONS https://varungarg.s3.amazonaws.com/?max-keys=0 403 (Forbidden).
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://varungarg.s3.amazonaws.com/?max-keys=0' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is being blocked because of CORS.
I'm not sure why request has origin header and null value but if you enable CORS on bucket for allowed-origin "*", this should solve the error.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html